# what is the difference between 'Float a = 3f' and 'Float a = 3.0' in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, literals

If I perform

```
  97346822*3f, result is 2.9204048E8,
```

however

```
 97346822*3.0 gives me 2.92040466E8.
```

Please explain.

Comment: The others have answered your question about the differing results.  But I should note that the _declaration_ you put in the title, `Float a = 3.0` (or `float a = 3.0`), will be rejected by the compiler because 3.0 is treated as a `double` and it doesn't like you forcing it into a variable with lower precision (without an explicit type cast).

Comment: Why are the questions in the title and body different?

Comment: You need to know that `float` is not the same as `Float` which is not the same as `double`.  Once you realise that the type actually matters, it is no surprise the answers are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number `3.0` is the [literal representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of a `double` value (it's equivalent to `3.0d`), whereas `3.0f` is a `float` value. The different precisions explain why you're getting different results - a `double` is stored using 64-bits, a `float` uses 32-bits.

Comment: 3.0 is exactly representable in both float and double, so there will be no difference for that particular case.

Comment: @Patricia: Correct, but the result of 97346822*3 is not exactly representable in a float.

Answer (score 3):

```
97346822*3.0
```

will be treated as `double`.

Based on [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values, this data type is generally the default choice.

```
97346822*3f
```

will be treated as `float`.

Answer (score 0):

These are findings related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17883463/1424875) and my answer to same.

While 3.0 and 3f both have the same value when put into floating point values, the actual value is used as working memory for the floating point operation. The internal values that are part of the multiplication do not fit into the floating point value themselves and are modified, resulting in a difference of 14.0 between the obtained results.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called as Numeric promotion in Java

> Numeric promotions are used to convert the operands(of an operation like multiplication, etc) of a numeric operator to a common type(smaller numeric type to a larger numeric type among the 2 datatypes of operands) to perform a specific operation

So in the example given by you, for `97346822*3f` since the 3f is a float value so the floating point operation is done and the result is of float type.

But 3.0 is a double type which has higher range and precision which causes the results to vary

So the value of 3.0 and 3f are same, but when these values are used in a numeric operation then the result will vary based on the datatype of the other operand