# Issues obtaining empirical evidence to show difference in internal storage between float and double

Tags: java

Someone asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865846/what-is-the-difference-between-float-a-3f-and-float-a-3-0-in-java) question yesterday.  I understand that java interprets `3.0` to be a `double`, and `3f` to be a `float`, and the `doubles` have 64-bit precision and `floats` have 32-bit precision.  If someone asked me, I would have given an answer similar to the ones given; however, I wanted to provide empirical evidence that made it very clear that `java` stores `3.0` and `3f` differently.

Here's what I attempted, but to little avail:

```
    System.out.println("Double: " + Double.toHexString(d)); //prints 0x1.8p1
    System.out.println("Float: " + Float.toHexString(f)); //prints 0x1.8p1

    System.out.println("Double: " + new Double(d).byteValue()); //prints 3
    System.out.println("Float: " + new Float(f).byteValue());  //prints 3 

    Long l = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
    Integer i = Float.floatToIntBits(f);

    System.out.println("Double (long bits): " + l); //prints 4613937818241073152
    System.out.println("Float (int bits): " + i); //prints 1077936128
```

These are different, but that's because `floats` use single-format (an 8-bit biased exponent), and `doubles` use double-format (an 11-bit biased exponent).  For more information, see [IEEE Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_math.html).  I converted both to their binary representations, but again didn't get anywhere:

```
    System.out.println("Long-toBinary: " + Long.toBinaryString(l)); 
    //prints 100000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    System.out.println("Integer-toBinary: " + Integer.toBinaryString(i)); 
    //prints 1000000010000000000000000000000
```

While there are more `0's` in the `Long.toBinaryString(l)`, multiplying by addition `0's` will not change the result (the differing position of the 1 in the beginning is due to the 8-bit vs 11-bit biased exponent issue).  So, I still don't have **empirical evidence** as to why the multiplication from the question below yields two different answers.

```
  97346822*3f, result is 2.9204048E8,
```

however

```
 97346822*3.0 gives me 2.92040466E8.
```

`3f` and `3.0` must be different for the results to be different, but I can not come up with anything **showing** that they actually are.  Again, I understand that `3f` is interpreted as a `float` and `3.0` as a `double`, please do not respond with answers merely stating this.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I am trying to **isolate** `3.0` and `3f` and show that they are indeed different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer also deals with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17884035/1424875).

## 3.0 and 3f themselves:

Their values are equal. We have some exponent and 2 consecutive ones in the value. This represents 3.0 and 3f equally. Now the problem is the floating-point multiplication. each floating point multiplication occurs on processor hardware, and all of the multiplication happens within a floating-point value itself, in the same precision(double/float). While the values `3.0` and `3f` are equal, they are not equal in regards to how a multiplication occurs with them. This does not matter with `strictfp` on my system as my CPU matches the IEEE 754 standard precisely.

### Other findings

This code could clue you in:

```
 BigDecimal val1=new BigDecimal(97346822*3f);
 BigDecimal val2=new BigDecimal(97346822*3.0);
 System.out.println(val1.subtract(val2, MathContext.UNLIMITED).toEngineeringString());
 System.out.println(val1.equals(val2));
 System.out.println(val1.compareTo(val2));
```

This creates two BigDecimals from our values.

First output is the difference as an engineering string, namely `14`, *not* `0`.

Second output is `false` showing that BigDecimal does not find them to be of equal value and precision.

Third output gives `1`. Therefore value 1 is greater than value 2 in the context of BigDecimal.

Printing both `precision(` results shows they both have a precision of 9.

### Different float/double values that can't be represented in binary without a repeating decimal

Let's run the same code with different values:

```
BigDecimal val1=new BigDecimal(3.1f);
BigDecimal val2=new BigDecimal(3.1);
System.out.println(val1.subtract(val2, MathContext.UNLIMITED).toEngineeringString()); //-95.367431729442841970012523233890533447265625E-9
System.out.println(val1.equals(val2)); //false
System.out.println(val1.compareTo(val2)); // -1
System.out.println(val1.precision()); // 22
System.out.println(val2.precision()); // 52
```

We can see that the same literal decimal, in float/double value, represents provably distinct values. In this case, the decimal 3.1 cannot be fit cleanly into a binary decimal. A similar effect happens with base 10 decimals and the fraction 2/3. While 2/3 would be written as:

```
  _
0.6
```

We'd write it with a limited length as 0.66666667. If we had a longer length, it would be something like 0.6666666666666667.

When taken literally, 0.66666667!=0.6666666666666667.

Comment: I understand that the products are different.  I'm trying to **isolate** the `3.0` and `3f` and compare their representations.

Comment: @SteveP. Namely 3.0 and 3f? Or any literal?

Comment: `3.0` and `3f` happened to be the values at hand for the other question.  So, I wanted to prove to the OP that at some level, the stored internal representations of `3.0` and `3f` are different.  I wanted to show this *atomically*, if you will.  As in, here's `3.0`.  Here's `3f`.  See, they're different.